# org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error adding field 'vector'

Tags: solr, knn, solrj

I cannot add the 'vector' field as per the documentation. I have tried multiple ways but it has not worked.

```
    final SolrInputDocument d1 = new SolrInputDocument();
    d1.setField("id", "1");
    d1.setField("vector", Arrays.asList(1.0f, 2.5f, 3.7f, 4.1f));


    final SolrInputDocument d2 = new SolrInputDocument();
    d2.setField("id", "2");
    d2.setField("vector", Arrays.asList(1.5f, 5.5f, 6.7f, 65.1f));

    solr.add(Arrays.asList(d1, d2));
```

Solr version: 9.2.0

SolrJ version: 9.2.0

https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/dense-vector-search.html

org.apache.solr.client.solrj.impl.BaseHttpSolrClient$RemoteSolrException: Error from server at http://localhost:8983/solr/core: ERROR: [doc=1] Error adding field 'vector'='[1.0, 2.5, 3.7, 4.1]' msg=Error while creating field 'vector{type=knn_vector,properties=indexed,stored,omitNorms,omitTermFreqAndPositions,useDocValuesAsStored}' from value '[1.0, 2.5, 3.7, 4.1]', expected format:'[f1, f2, f3...fn]' e.g. [1.0, 3.4, 5.6]] with root cause

I was able to add same field from python and rest api.